# Transformar em Submenu

Tags: php, html

Fiz uma mudança aqui sobre os códigos do menu e os códigos estava com erros

O Nosso amigo Hugocsl mandou eu pesquisar outro menu e achei

Só tenho uma duvida como faço para o menu ficar responsivo?

Outro erro ao clicar na certa duas vezes ele não volta no mesmo lugar

E na opção dos menus não tem links tem como colocar os link?

Site

[Swanky Pure CSS Drop Down Menu](https://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/qdWxEm)

Comment: Jovem sua pergunta não ficou muito clara... aparentemente seu itens já estão dentro de Produtos não? Outra coisa, edite sua pergunta e inclua também o CSS completo, só com o HTML não da para te ajudar muito...

Comment: Cara está faltando código ai... cade o elemento com o id `#nav-left`? Vc está usando algum framework tipo Bootstrap etc? Está usando Java Script ou jQuery?

Comment: @hugocsl Pronto amigo ai está todos os código HTML

Comment: Pelo visto vc quer que quando clicar no Produtos ele "abra" expandindo e mostrando os itens que estão dentro, e se clicar novamente ele "recolhe" se fechando e escondendo os itens correto?

Comment: @hugocsl Isto amigo, é exatamente isto mesmo, ai quando clicar no botão abaixo que ele fique a onde eu estou fixo

Comment: Não entendi essa parte *ai quando clicar no botão abaixo que ele fique a onde eu estou fixo* o que vc quis dizer com isso?

Comment: @hugocsl Ao clicar que fique parado no lugar a onde eu estou no link para não voltar para o botão principal do PRODUTO

Comment: @hugocsl amigo está dando certo?

Comment: Pesquise por "collapse menu" vai te ajudar a encontrar algo pronto

Comment: @hugocsl amigo achei um menu Show mim ajuda agora

Comment: Veja a resposta como ficou, qualquer coisa é só comentar lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** - Para fazer o link é só envolver o texto dentro da `LI` em uma tag `A`. Só fiz para a primeira opção do menu *Dashboard*

**2** - Para deixar responsivo basta colocar o componente com `width` de 100%

**3** - Para poder abrir e fechar o menu basta vc trocar o `type:radio` por `type:checkbox`

Veja como fica o resultado:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300);
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body .swanky {
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #8254EA 0%, #E86DEC 100%);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 12px;
}
body .swanky {
  -webkit-perspective: 600px;
          perspective: 600px;
  /* width: 700px; */
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  /* height: 360px; */
}
body .swanky_title {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  width: 400px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
}
body .swanky_title__social a {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
body .swanky_title__social a .slide {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
          transform: skew(20deg);
  left: -120px;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  background: white;
}
body .swanky_title__social a .slide .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 31px;
  top: 24px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
          transform: skew(-20deg);
}
body .swanky_title__social a .slide .arrow .stem {
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #858490;
}
body .swanky_title__social a .slide .arrow .point {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-right: 2px solid #858490;
  top: -3px;
  right: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-top: 2px solid #858490;
}
body .swanky_title__social a img {
  width: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 8px;
  transition-property: margin-left;
  transition-duration: .1s;
  margin-top: 10px;
  top: 4px;
}
body .swanky_title__social a:hover > .slide {
  left: -70px;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: .1s;
}
body .swanky_title__social a:hover > img {
  margin-left: 40px;
  transition-property: margin-left;
  transition-duration: .1s;
}
body .swanky_title__social a:hover > .slide .arrow {
  right: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-property: right,opacity;
  transition-delay: .07s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
}
body .swanky .intro {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  width: 370px;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
body .swanky .intro h1 {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
body .swanky .intro p {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
body .swanky_wrapper {
  /* width: 225px; */
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #2a394f;
}
body .swanky_wrapper label {
  padding: 25px;
  float: left;
  height: 72px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #293649;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #eff4fa;
  transition: text-indent .15s, height .3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body .swanky_wrapper label img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  width: 16px;
}
body .swanky_wrapper label span {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
body .swanky_wrapper label:hover {
  background: #212e41;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2A394F;
  text-indent: 4px;
}
body .swanky_wrapper label:hover .bar {
  width: 100%;
}
body .swanky_wrapper label .bar {
  width: 0px;
  transition: width .15s;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #355789;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
body .swanky_wrapper label .lil_arrow {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  right: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}
body .swanky_wrapper__content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
body .swanky_wrapper__content li {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
  background: #15a4fa;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1  inset;
  transition: box-shadow .3s,text-indent .3s;
  position: relative;
}
body .swanky_wrapper__content li:hover {
  background: #0c93e4;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px #126CA1  inset;
  transition: box-shadow .3s linear,text-indent .3s linear;
  text-indent: 31px;
}
body .swanky_wrapper__content .clear {
  clear: both;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label .swanky_wrapper__content {
  display: block;
  top: 68px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212e41;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label > .lil_arrow {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s, -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  border-top: 2px solid #14a3f9;
  border-right: 2px solid #14a3f9;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
  height: 325px;
  background: #212e41;
  text-indent: 4px;
  transition-property: height;
  transition-duration: .6s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label .bar {
  width: 0;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
          animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
  from {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes in {
  from {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.love {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.love p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.love a {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.love img {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  width: 10px;
}

.brand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 14px;
}
.brand img {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!-- / Begin Body -->
<div class='swanky'>

  <!-- /////////// Begin Dropdown //////////// -->
  <div class='swanky_wrapper'>
    <input id='Dashboard' name='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Dashboard'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/dash.png'>
      <span>Dashboard</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='swanky_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Code Blocks</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Sales' name='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Sales'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/del.png'>
      <span>Sales</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='swanky_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>New Sales</li>
          <li>Expired Sales</li>
          <li>Sales Reports</li>
          <li>Deliveries</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Messages' name='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Messages'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/mess.png'>
      <span>Messages</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='swanky_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>Inbox</li>
          <li>Outbox</li>
          <li>Sent</li>
          <li>Archived</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Users' name='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Users'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/users.png'>
      <span>Users</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='bar'></div>
      <div class='swanky_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>New User</li>
          <li>User Groups</li>
          <li>Permissions</li>
          <li>Passwords</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input id='Settings' checkbox='checkbox' type='checkbox'>
    <label for='Settings'>
      <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/set.png'>
      <span>Settings</span>
      <div class='lil_arrow'></div>
      <div class='swanky_wrapper__content'>
        <ul>
          <li>Databases</li>
          <li>Design</li>
          <li>Change User</li>
          <li>Log Out</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <!-- /////////// End Dropdown //////////// -->
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo tem como adicionar mais campos de links? eu adicionei mas não foi reconhecido

Comment: @Angelino primeiramente muito cuidado com esses componentes que vc não domina completamente, vc pode ter problemas mais sérios com eles... No caso de adicionar mais link basta vc ir fazendo `input[type='checkbox']:checked + label li:nth-of-type(5) { }` e `(6)` `(7)` e quantos nth-of-type vc precisar, só lembre que em cada um deles vc tb vai precisar ajustar a `animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;` mudando o tempo da animação ali no 0.15s 0.95s e aumentando esse tempo para cada novo link. De uma olhada nessa parte do CSS onde estão os `nth-of-type` que vc vai entender melhor o que estou falando

Comment: Obrigado amigo, consegui

Comment: Amigo o que ouve com a minha conta aqui? eu não posso mais postar o amigo poderia mim ajudar pôquer?

Comment: @Angelino cara ate olhei seu perfil para ver se tinha algum alerta Pq quando a pessoa toma alguma punição e não pode postar ela recebe um aviso. Mas parece que não eh seu caso. Não sei te dizer o que aconteceu, mas no rodapé aqui do site a esquerda tem o chat e o meta, vc pós e entrar lar e fazer uma pergunta colocando todos os detalhes, avisos ou erros que apareceu ai. Desculpe não poder fazer mais, mas la as vezes alguém sabe